# Algorithm to determine closest Rectangles

Tags: linear-algebra

Maybe this question belongs to StackOverflow but maybe someone here has a good idea to solve or optimize my approach to following problem:

Let's say we've a set $S$ of rectangles in Euclidean Coordinates. Those rectangles are form some sort of clusters hence, some are quite close to one another while others are not. The task is to group the rectangles which are close to one another.

The problem is that I'm not able to determine something like a general distance to identify if a rectangle belongs to a cluster or not.

My approach so far is as follows:

I introduce a new set $C$ and a initial distance $d$ and iterate over each element in $S$. If a the an element $s_i$ of $S$ is in the distance of $c_j$ element $C$, using the centers of $s_i$ and $c_j$  to calculate the Euclidean distance between this vectors, I adjust $c_j$ to a combination of both rectangles. If not, $s_i$ becomes a new element of $C$. As this progresses, i adjust the distance $d$ by multiplication with the term $(1-(1/avg(c_j))$ where $avg(c_j)$ is the average distance between all merged rectangles of $c_j$.

This works quite well in some cases but it's heavily depending on the initial distance. Any help from a mathematical perspective would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
The rectangles are always parallel to the x- and y-axis and of different sizes. They don't necessarily overlap to belong to a cluster. It's sometimes the case but they are often separated by some space.

Comment: I think this is the right site for this question.  It would be look down at on stack overflow.

Comment: Can the rectangles be oriented in random directions or are they "parallel"?

Comment: They are just parallel.

Comment: There are some things that are not exactly clear: 1) are the rectangles of the same size? 2) are the side parallel? If yes, are the corners on a regular grid? 3) do they need to overlap to belong to the same cluster? I see you already replied to one of the questions

Comment: I edited the question accordingly

Comment: "The task is to group the rectangles which are close to one another". This does not adequately explain the type of clustering. You could mean a configuration that minimizes the average in-cluster distance or that which minimizes the maximum clustering distance, or any number of other DISTINCT clustering criteria.
You should provide the exact goal.

There are diameter independent approximate clustering algorithms, so a dependency on distance may be avoidable.

Comment: It might help Readers to give an idea of the purpose to which the *clustering* will be put.  There are many algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

First, you might want to define your rectangle objects as having the following five characteristics:

1. index
2. $x$ coordinate of lower left vertex
3. $\Delta x$ as width of rectangle
4. $y$ as $y$ coordinate of lower left vertex
5. $\Delta y$ as height of rectangle
6. Cluster number (initially = index)

Decide in advance that two rectangles within a distance $\epsilon$ of each other belong to the same cluster. Then *augment* each rectangle as in the diagram, adding a border region of width $\epsilon/2$ to all four sides. This is accomplished by taking each $x,\Delta x,y,\Delta y$ for each of the original rectangles and replacing them as follows:

$$x\to x-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\,\Delta x\to\Delta x+\epsilon,\,y\to y-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\,\Delta y\to\Delta y+\epsilon$$

Use these as the augmented vertices for each rectangle.

[image: Augmented rectangle]

Assuming $N$ rectangles,

Initially, assign each rectangle $R_i$ to it's own individual cluster $C_i$. Then

for $1\le i<j\le N$

if $x_j\le x_i+\Delta x_i\le x_j+\Delta x_j$

and

if $y_j\le x_i+\Delta y_i\le x_j+\Delta y_j$

then assign $x_j$ to $C_i$ and mark cluster $C_j$ as eliminated.

Remember, these are the augmented rectangles. Making the value of $\epsilon$ larger will result in the merger of more clusters. Making $\epsilon$ smaller will break up some clusters into smaller clusters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. What would you do to merge the closest clusters?

Comment: You would need a measure of "closeness" for clusters. Perhaps specify a "closeness" square. If a square of a pre-specified area could be positioned to intersect two clusters, $C_i,\,C_j, i<j$ then merge $C_j$ into $C_i$ and mark $C_j$ as eliminated. Alternately, one could just add an $\epsilon$ to the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the original rectangles to handle the closeness of clusters problem and just run the procedure in my answer with no further processing. Just stick with the clusters produced by that step. Probably the best way to do it.

Comment: That's what I've tried using the cluster centers and the Euclidean distance which I decrease over time. I've also created a vector of certain properties and used the cosine similarity the check similarity between the clusters. But this approach has certain pitfalls.

Comment: Suppose you had in mind an $\epsilon>0$ such that if a corner of a rectangle were within $\epsilon$ of another rectangle, then they would be in the same cluster. This could be accomplished by initially changing the four vertices of each $R$ from $(x,y),(x+\Delta x,y),(x,y+\Delta y),(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)$ to $(x-\epsilon/2,y-\epsilon/2),(x+\Delta x+\epsilon/2,y-\epsilon/2),(x-\epsilon/2,y+\Delta y+\epsilon/2),(x+\Delta x+\epsilon/2,y+\Delta y+\epsilon/2)$.